# implementing malloc with mmap

Tags: c, memory-management

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475609/implementing-your-own-malloc-free-with-mmap-and-munmap).

Is this a good implementation of *malloc* using `mmap`?

***memory.hpp***

```
#ifndef MEMORY_HPP
#define MEMORY_HPP

void *malloc(unsigned int);
void *calloc(unsigned int);
void free(void *);

#endif
```

***memory.cpp***

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791310/c-mmap-initialize-at-0xffffffff
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475609/implementing-your-own-malloc-free-with-mmap-and-munmap
#include "memory.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

void *malloc(unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int *plen;
    unsigned int len = size + sizeof(size); // Add sizeof( size ) for holding length.

    plen = (unsigned int *)mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

    if (plen == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("map failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    *plen = len;               // First 4 bytes contain length.
    return (void *)(&plen[1]); // Memory that is after length variable.
}

void *calloc(unsigned int size)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    memset(ptr, 0, size);
    return ptr;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    unsigned int *plen = (unsigned int *)ptr - 1; // Get length variable.
    munmap(plen, *plen);
}
```

Comment: Is this your code or someone else's? Are you familiar with a standard implementation like dlmalloc?

Comment: You might want to read some of the answers on the questions on Stack Overflow you pointed to, for instance use `size_t` rather than unsigned int. The type `size_t` is what the `sizeof()` function returns.

Comment: This lacks a `realloc()`. And both `malloc()` and `calloc()` would be better off mapping copy-on-write pages from the `/dev/zero` device or equivalent than allocating pages and then overwriting them.

Comment: Specifying both contradicting SHARE-flags is out of spec: [Either MAP_SHARED or MAP_PRIVATE can be specified, but not both.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

Answer (score 2):

Some limitations of this implementation include:

There is no `realloc()`.

This implementation uses `unsigned int` rather than `size_t`, so it does not follow the Standard, and can only allocate 32 bits on most 64-bit implementations.

It passes a value of `-1` as the file descriptor, [which is not conformant to the POSIX standard.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

For most applications, it would be better to map [copy-on-write pages from a device like `/dev/zero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507945/mmap-with-dev-zero) that only get mapped into physical memory if they are used than for `calloc()` to touch every page of memory and write zeroes to it.  In addition to taking much more time, this will evict other pages of memory from your cache and cause cache misses when `calloc()` returns.

Although you are not required by the specification to have `free()` do any error-checking at all, it is a very bad idea to fail silently and leave the program in an unstable state.

Finally, although you know this already, real-world implementations of `malloc()` only use this scheme for large allocations, and allocate smaller blocks from a heap.

Answer (score 2):

**Alignment requirements not certainly met.**

The standard library `*alloc()` functions return pointers that are "suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement".  OP's code makes no provision for the returned pointer to be so aligned.  Research `max_align_t`.